# Beginner Python3: Questions About the Turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the exercise [Lessons from a Triangle](http://www.example.com/)!

```
import turtle

def drawPolygon(t, sideLength, numSides):
    turnAngle = 360 / numSides
    for i in range(numSides):
    t.forward(sideLength)
    t.left(turnAngle)

def drawFilledCircle(anyTurtle, radius, vcolor):

    anyTurtle.fillcolor(vcolor)
    anyTurtle.begin_fill()
    circumference = 2 * 3.1415 * radius
    sideLength = circumference / 360
    drawPolygon(anyTurtle, sideLength, 360)
    anyTurtle.end_fill()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wheel = turtle.Turtle()


drawFilledCircle(wheel, 20, 'purple')

wn.exitonclick()
```

1) How come when I try to change the speed of the turtle like wheel.speed(10) it doesn't work? What's the default speed if I don't indicate the speed?

2) How do i put my turtle to the middle of the circle once it's done?

Thank You so Much!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Where are you trying to do it? What are you expecting to happen? What's happening instead?

Comment: The rest of your questions are covered in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html). (And I'll bet the second question is also covered in detail in whatever place you got that exercise from, but since you linked to http://example.com it's hard to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

As abarnert said, the link to your exercise is broken, but there are a few things you can do to speed up your program. FWIW, the turtle module has a `.circle` method, but I guess the point of your exercise is to use a polygon to approximate a circle.

`wheel.speed(10)` *does* work (although `wheel.speed(0)` is even faster). It doesn't appear to make much difference because the sides of your 360-sided polygon are so tiny, and so the turtle has to do several moves & turns just to traverse a single pixel.

Using a 360-sided polygon to draw a circle, no matter what the radius is, is not a great strategy. The code below determines the number of sides from the circumference so that each side is approximately 1 pixel. This will look good for a circle of any radius, and it avoids doing too much work for small circles.

Apart from using `turtle.speed` to speed things up you can also reduce the canvas's frame delay. Also, if you hide the turtle while drawing, it'll go even faster.

The following code was tested on Python 2.6.6; it should also work without modification on Python 3.x, but on Python 3.x you may remove the `from __future__ import division, print_function` line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Approximate a circle using a polygon

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/30475519/4014959

    Code revised by PM 2Ring 2015.05.27
'''

from __future__ import division, print_function

import turtle

def drawPolygon(t, sideLength, numSides):
    turnAngle = 360 / numSides
    for i in range(numSides):
        t.forward(sideLength)
        t.left(turnAngle)


def drawFilledCircle(anyTurtle, radius, vcolor):
    anyTurtle.fillcolor(vcolor)
    anyTurtle.begin_fill()

    circumference = 2 * 3.14159 * radius

    #Calculate number of sides so that each side is approximately 1 pixel
    numSides = int(0.5 + circumference)
    sideLength = circumference / numSides
    print('side length = {0}, number of sides = {1}'.format(sideLength, numSides))

    drawPolygon(anyTurtle, sideLength, numSides)
    anyTurtle.end_fill()


wn = turtle.Screen()

#Set minimum canvas update delay
wn.delay(1)

wheel = turtle.Turtle()

#Set fastest turtle speed
wheel.speed(0)
#wheel.hideturtle()

radius = 20

#Move to the bottom of the circle, so 
#that the filled circle will be centered.
wheel.up()
wheel.goto(0, -radius)
wheel.down()

drawFilledCircle(wheel, radius, 'purple')

#Move turtle to the center of the circle
wheel.up()
wheel.goto(0, 0)
#wheel.showturtle()

wn.exitonclick()
```